# List custom post type but redirects to home page

Tags: custom-post-types, archives

here is my problem. It's been around 2 hours that I try to have a page listing all projects (they are a Custom Post Type) so I'm trying to have an archive file named archive-projects.php but when I try to access it with /projects/ , it redirects me to the home.php instead of a 404 error. I'm kinda lost there.
This is my register_post_type maybe it can help.

```
function projetPostType()
    {
        register_post_type('projects',
            array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __('Projects'),
                    'singular_name' => __('Project'),
                    'add_new' => __('Add project'),
                    'add_new_item' => __('Add project'),
                    'edit' => __('Edit'),
                    'edit_item' => __('Edit project'),
                    'new_item' => __('New project'),
                    'view' => __('View project'),
                    'view_item' => __('View the project'),
                    'search_items' => __('Search project'),
                    'not_found' => __('No project')
                ),
                'hierarchical' => false,
                'public' => true,
                'menu_position' => 30,
                'has_archive' => true,
                'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'projects'),
                'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
                'description' => 'Project contains a text and title',
                'exclude_from_search' => true,
                'publicly_queryable' => false,
                'show_in_admin_bar' => true,                                            
                'register_meta_box_cb' => 'gererBoiteProjets'
            )
        );
    }
```

I don't have any plugin so it's not coming from there. If you need more informations, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Flush your permalinks - by which I mean simply visit the Permalinks page under Settings.

Then check /projects again.

EDIT:

Remove

```
'publicly_queryable' => false,
```

from your arguments. It prevents rewrites.

Comment: I just visited the Permalinks section and even clicked "Save" just to be sure but no, still redirect me to home.php

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: Yeah it worked and realized why it didn'T work, thanks a lot mate !

Comment: The publicly_queryable hint worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Using `'hierarchical' => true` was the issue for me. As soon as I changed it to `false`, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with my custom post type. After i flushed the permalink settings, i deleted the the page(which uses the template i created for custom post type) from the pages list and created a new one and used it and it was working fine.

My understanding is that when we flush, we sometimes don't know if they are actually flushed or not.

Answer (score -5):

Or, check if the 'Has Archive' checkbox is active.. *ashamed* ;-)

Comment: There is no such checkbox in WordPress. Please explain your answer.